# How to prevent the sensitive data used by app in android?

Tags: android, privacy

As we all know Android app apk file can be drilled down to get the Java codes and resources. The sensitive data used to populate lets say list view used as arrays in Java files can be easily hacked.

What are the secure ways to do it?

I guess downloading XML or JSON file from the internet and using in app? Or there any other techniques?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: google is your friend, please do some research first at the very least... https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore

Comment: Data used to populate a list view is publicly visible anyway - what sort of data are you concerned about exposing?

Comment: @WilomGfx Its not about keystore, I want to compare between data stored in arrays vs other techniques i.e external xml, json files stored in remote server

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie : It does not necessarily needs to be visible all the data in listview. For instance http links of some songs.

Comment: You answered the question yourself: if you have sensitive data, you DON'T hardcode that data into the app. Instead you obtain it from a different source (in most cases a web service that uses industry standard encryption).

Comment: Somebody can always build his own client to fetch all the data from the server. The app shows how to get access.

Comment: @JanusVarmarken, Henry : Well, that was my wild guess. I expect some professional confirm this with formal resources.

Comment: @Henry after a research  i found fetching from server can also be tracked by monitoring http requests it sends from mobile device

Comment: Normally you would not use http for anything sensitive. Always use https.